# Use data in HTML Grid returned from ajax in MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to fetch data from server and use it in a HTML grid. HTML Grid code is:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper-Baby" class="wrapper">
        <div class="Product" style="width:100%">
            <header class="product-header">
                <div class="product-image-container">
                    <a class="product-image-link" OnClick="window.location.href='@Url.Action("Details", "Home", new { id = item.ItemID })'">
                        <div class="product-image">
                            <img alt="@item.ItemName" src="@item.ImageUrl" />
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="product-main-info">
                    <h3 class="product-title">
                        <a OnClick="window.location.href='@Url.Action("Details", "Home", new { id = item.ItemID })'">
                            <span>
                                <span class="product-brand">
                                    @item.BrandName
                                </span>
                                <span class="product-name">
                                    @item.ItemName
                                </span>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </h3>
                    <span class="product-pricing-info">
                        <span class="price-container">
                            <span class="currency-sign">Rs.</span>
                            <span class="rs-value">
                                @item.ItemPrice
                            </span>
                            <span class="paisa-value">.00</span>
                        </span>
                        <span class="saving-container">
                            <!----to be filled-->
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="product-info">
                    <p>
                        <span class="package-size">
                            <!--to be filled-->
                        </span>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </header>
            <div class="product-actions-container">
                <div class="fat-controller is-full-width">
                    <div class="fc-button" id="fcButton">
                        <div class="button-main-container clear">
                            <a href="/ShoppingCart/AddToCart/@item.ItemID/1" class="button button-main">
                                <span class="button-main-inner">
                                    <span>
                                        Add
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="product-qty">1</span>
                                    <span class="product-text">for</span>
                                    <strong class="product-price">Rs. @item.ItemPrice</strong>
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <button class="button button-down">
                            <svg focusable="false" class="icon icon-dropdown-small">
                                <use xlink:href="#icon-dropdown-small">
                                    <symbol viewBox="0 0 9 4" id="icon-dropdown-small">
                                        <path d="M4.092,3.999 C4.092,3.999 0.008,0.002 0.008,0.002 C0.008,0.002 8.177,0.002 8.177,0.002 C8.177,0.002 4.092,3.999 4.092,3.999 Z" id="icon-dropdown-small-path-1" fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
                                    </symbol>
                                </use>
                            </svg>
                        </button>
                        <div class="button-confirmation">
                            <div class="button-confirmation-container clear">
                                <div class="button-confirmation-label">
                                    <span data-colrs-fat-controller-animation-message=""></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="button-confirmation-icon">
                                <span class="icon-loading"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!---->
                        <div class="fc-dropdown">
                            <span class="popup-arrow"></span>
                            <ul class="fc-button-options" id="fcDropDown">
                                <!---->
                                <li class="fc-option">
                                    <a href="/ShoppingCart/AddToCart/@item.ItemID/1" class="button-add button-measure">
                                        <svg focusable="false" class="icon icon-tick">
                                            <use xlink:href="#icon-tick"></use>
                                        </svg>
                                        <!---->
                                        <span class="combined">
                                            <span class="product-qty" style="width: 12px;">1&nbsp;</span>
                                            <span class="product-text">for&nbsp;</span>
                                            <strong class="product-price" style="width: 52px;">@item.ItemPrice</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <!---->
                                <li class="fc-option">
                                    <a href="/ShoppingCart/AddToCart/@item.ItemID/2" class="button-add button-measure">
                                        <svg focusable="false" class="icon icon-tick">
                                            <use xlink:href="#icon-tick"></use>
                                        </svg>
                                        <!---->
                                        <span class="combined">
                                            <span class="product-qty" style="width: 12px;">2&nbsp;</span>
                                            <span class="product-text">for&nbsp;</span>
                                            <strong class="product-price" style="width: 52px;">@(item.ItemPrice * 2)</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="fc-option">
                                    <a href="/ShoppingCart/AddToCart/@item.ItemID/3" class="button-add button-measure">
                                        <svg focusable="false" class="icon icon-tick">
                                            <use xlink:href="#icon-tick"></use>
                                        </svg>
                                        <!---->
                                        <span class="combined">
                                            <span class="product-qty" style="width: 12px;">3&nbsp;</span>
                                            <span class="product-text">for&nbsp;</span>
                                            <strong class="product-price" style="width: 52px;">@(item.ItemPrice * 3)</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="fc-option">
                                    <a href="/ShoppingCart/AddToCart/@item.ItemID/4" class="button-add button-measure">
                                        <svg focusable="false" class="icon icon-tick">
                                            <use xlink:href="#icon-tick"></use>
                                        </svg>
                                        <!---->
                                        <span class="combined">
                                            <span class="product-qty" style="width: 12px;">4&nbsp;</span>
                                            <span class="product-text">for&nbsp;</span>
                                            <strong class="product-price" style="width: 52px;">@(item.ItemPrice * 4)</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>

                                <li class="fc-option fc-option-more">
                                    <button class="button-more button-measure">
                                        <svg focusable="false" class="icon icon-tick">
                                            <use xlink:href="#icon-tick"></use>
                                        </svg>
                                        <span class="option-more combined" style="width: 93px;">
                                            <span class="product-text">
                                                <span class="product-qty" style="width: 12px;">
                                                    5
                                                </span> or more...
                                            </span>
                                        </span>
                                    </button>

                                    @using (Html.BeginForm("AddToCart", "ShoppingCart", new { id = item.ItemID }, FormMethod.Post))
                                    {
                                        <div class="fc-option-more-input ng-hide">
                                            <input type="number" id="itemCount" name="itemCount" class="ItemCount">
                                            <button type="submit" class="button button-add-custom-qty" id=@item.ItemID disabled="disabled">
                                                <!----><span>Add</span><!---->
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    }
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

I'm pasting all this code because I need to show my page in this format. I need to pass following variable values to Grid from ajax success:

@item.ItemName, @item.ImageUrl, item.ItemID, @item.BrandName, @item.ItemName

So for that, I needed to fetch the list of items from server. This JavaScript code is used to call data from the controller on a button click:

**JavaScript**:

```
$(".CategoryAnchors").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            // Get the category name given in the id from the button
            var category = this.id;
            // Perform the ajax post
            if (category != '') {
                $.post("/Home/GetCategoryItems",
                    {
                        "categoryName": category
                    },
                    function (data) {
                        //successful request gets here
                        //Update page element
                        $("#wrapperShop").css('visibility', 'hidden');
                    }
                )
            }
        });
```

**Controller:**

```
public JsonResult GetCategoryItems (string categoryName)
        {
            var itemList = db.Items.Where(x => x.CategoryName == categoryName).ToList();
            return Json(itemList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

I might be trying to do a wrong logic for the process but if it's possible this way, please advice how I can pass relevant data to from AJAX to my HTML Grid.

**.CSS**

```
#wrapper-Baby {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 214px 214px 214px 214px 214px 214px;
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(20px, auto);
    grid-gap: 15px;
    margin-top: 0;
    position: relative;
    left: 12px;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 880px;    
}
```

Comment: you can't re-use the things like `@item.ItemName` etc - they are C# Razor code which ran on the server when the page was first being created. Instead, inside the "success" function you have to write some JavaScript which locates the HTML elements which wrap around those values and change their content. For example, the ItemName is inside the element `<span class="product-brand">`, so you'd have to locate that item (e.g. using `document.querySelector())` and replace its `innerText` content with a new value which comes from the response JSON data.

Comment: Or, it's not clear but perhaps you actually need to clear the grid and re-build it with the new values? Because I would guess that you would need to replace the form definition, as well as the displayed values, that kind of thing. You might actually be better off using a Partial View rather than JSON here. Then you can re-use the Razor code in the AJAX context as well as when the page first loads.

Comment: @ADyson - I mentioned `@item.ItemName` etc., variables only to explain what values I need in the markup. Yes I'm only building grid with values returned from  the Ajax response data. Basic idea is to fetch data from the ajax response (only) and use those values in the grid where things like `@item.ItemName` etc., are otherwise being used. If you think there is a way to do it and it is better than using Partial views, please advice accordingly. Thanks

Comment: Well I would advise using some sort of templating engine, whether client or server-side. Server-side is obviously a partial view. Client-side...there are many options for generating HTML snippets and injecting JSON data into them, you can find plenty of free ones online. Or you could just build the HTML strings by hand, but that's more fiddly to code, harder to read, and a lot less maintainable.

Comment: OK. But why can't I use above template?

Comment: You can, if you use server-side partial views. But you have to move it into the partial view, and then make the GetCategoryItems() method return the result of rendering the partial view.

Comment: If the template above is simply part of your view, then you can't use it after the ajax call runs, because the template is a Razor _server-side_ template. Your JavaScript code knows nothing about it. All it sees is some existing HTML in the page. Now, you could _clone_ that (or part of it) from the DOM and set about adjusting it to contain the new values...but that's a really awkward way to do it.

Comment: Thing is, I've a left side menu like here on this page (https://shop.coles.com.au/a/a-national/everything/browse). So when user clicks on a button, all product relevant to that product start showing on the very same page. I'm trying to do the exact thing. Above template is a theme for every product and I can't change it. I've to use the same theme all over my website. Kindly advice what are my best options. Thank you.

Comment: if you have to re-use this code in different views then it sounds like an ideal use case for a Partial View

Comment: Sure. Thank you for guiding me into a better direction Sir. Have a nice day.